# Strange characters as a result of HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create site parser for telegram bot. The exact code is:

```
var link = "https://www.detmir.ru/";
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(link);
var resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
string result;
using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding(resp.CharacterSet)))
    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

File.WriteAllText(@"d:\1.txt", result);
```

Result is a set of strange symbols:

[image: Strange symbols pics]

As far as I get - the main clue in encoding. I've tried to use Encoding.Defult, Encoding.UTF8 with the same result. 
But with other sites it works perfectly. Is there any trick to solve issue with this certain website?

**Update**

In Google Chrome the source code of webpage shows correctly:
[Google Chrome webpage source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h5M7.png)

Comment: One possibility is that you're getting the correct results, but don't have a character set installed capable of displaying Russian characters?  Not something I have much experience with sadly, so just a guess...

Comment: The site reports to use UTF-8. Is that editor you show capable of rendering Unicode?

Comment: ps. what IDE / editor are you using?

Comment: @JohnLBevan yes, I have the character set (update added). Actually it is more viewer than editor - FAR manager.

Comment: @CodeCaster yes, it supports UTF-8

Comment: `Content-Encoding: gzip` it's also possible that the content hasn't been uncompressed and you're looking at the compressed source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The contents of the response is UTF-8, as the site reports, but it is compressed to increase throughput performance.

Enable automatic decompression:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(link);
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
```

Comment: It works, thank you!